# First child in xml document using SQLXML

Tags: sql-server, xml

I have an bit of XML that I want to get the first child from.  So far, I've been able to do it thusly:

```
DECLARE @x XML = '<a><b foo="bar">some data</b><b foo="baz"/></a>'
SELECT @x.query('(/a/child::*)[1]')
```

I'm just wondering if there's a more efficient way.  My problem is that the element following the "a" tag is unknown to me until run-time, so just saying

```
@x.query('(/a/b)[1]')
```

isn't going to work for me.  The tag after "a" could just as well be "c" and I'd like for one query to account for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work for you:

```
SELECT @x.query('(/a/*[1])')
```

Comment: This seems to suffer from the same problem as my query does. Namely, it's specifying a "grab everything" approach and then taking the first element. Unless this is somehow optimized (which I'd like reference to if that's the case).

Comment: I'm afraid that unless you know the node type of the first child, you'll have to use the * selector.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
DECLARE @x XML = '<a><b foo="bar">some data</b><b foo="baz"/></a>'
SELECT @x.query('(/a/*)[1]')
```

It's actually the exact same query under the hood, as the child axis is the default one in xpath. Also, this should be efficient.

Comment: This seems to suffer from the same problem as my query does.  Namely, it's specifying a "grab everything" approach and then taking the first element.  Unless this is somehow optimized (which I'd like reference to if that's the case).